# KSQL SERVER & Application Parallelism

Tags: ksqldb

Let say i have a topic with 5 partition ? How do i ensure that with only one KSQL Server, 5 applications will be created to match the maximum parallelism ?

In short, can a KSQL Server run multiple applications (i.e. Kafka stream application) ? If yes how do I tell the number of instances of a query to run ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one KSQL Server can run multiple applications as long as it has enough resources & capacity. KSQL server uses the default configuration in order to run a query. You need to make sure that in order to achieve maximum parallelism, you can tune the default values.

For instance if the `num.stream.threads` is set to 3 by default and you want to achieve max parallelism, you can update the property as given below:

```
SET 'ksql.streams.num.stream.threads'='5';
```

There are some good documentation about Capacity Planning & configuration :

https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/capacity-planning.html#ksql-capacity-planning

https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/installation/server-config/config-reference.html#ksql-configuration-parameter-reference